# Why does my C array remember old data from a previous function call?

Tags: arrays, c

When I run the following C code I get the values:

- 222222222
- 312222222
- 102222222

I was expecting the values:

- 222222222
- 31
- 10

Why does the char number[] defined in my intToStr function remember previous values? I thought once the function call ended all local data was more or less destroyed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void intToStr(int n);

int main(void)
{
    intToStr(222222222);
    intToStr(31);
    intToStr(10);

    return 0;
}

void intToStr(int n)
{
    char number[10];

    int l = 0;
    if (n < 0)
    {
        l++;
        number[0] = '-';
        n *= -1;
    }
    int nCopy = n;

    while (nCopy > 9)
    {
        nCopy /= 10;
        l++;
    }

    int r;
    while (n > 9)
    {
        r = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        number[l--] = r + '0';
    }
    number[l] = n + '0';

    printf("%s\n", number);
}
```

Comment: In C, strings must be terminated by a character with value `0`.  You haven't done that. So `printf` keeps going until a zero is found in random memory you didn't intend to print.

Comment: "more or less destroyed" No and because you're not null terminating the string, you'll print beyond what you desire, with behavior that is not defined by any standard. You'll want to allocate more bytes to `number`. For a 10 digit number you need 11 bytes otherwise you'll encounter more undefined behavior.

Comment: I re-ran the code with a '\0' character at the last position in the array and I still get the same results. Why would the array still remember the previous data though when the function ends?

Comment: Probably because the storage for `number` is on the stack, because it's a local variable of a function, and if nothing else executes, and you call the function again, from the same function, then you'll likely have the same bytes as before on the stack in that same location.  The point is that you did not initialize the bytes of `number`, and did not  (originally) null-terminate your string.

Comment: @Wyck Yes I believe you're right about that. I just tried running it again but this time inserting random code between the function calls and now the arrays are filled with random data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's undefined behavior. If only the first 3 character are set, it may print `312222222` or it may print `312???????????????????`

The last characters in `char number[10]` are not initialized, that means the compiler may decide to leave it alone and the old values stay, or something else happens.

Otherwise `printf` doesn't know where the string end, it keeps printing until it randomly hits a zero.

If there is buffer overrun `printf` finds a different set of characters in memory (which we are not supposed to be accessing) and the program keeps printing those same characters until it randomly hits a zero and finally stops.

To fix it, simply make sure there is `'\0'` at the end. You can also add additional check to make sure the length does not exceed the buffer size

Working example:

```
char number[10];
int l = 0;
if (n < 0)
{
    l++;
    number[0] = '-';
    n *= -1;
}
if (n < 0) return;

int nCopy = n;
while (nCopy > 9)
{
    nCopy /= 10;
    l++;
}

int len = l;
if (len + 1 > sizeof(number))
    return;
number[len + 1] = '\0';

int r;
while (n > 9)
{
    r = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    number[l--] = r + '0';
}
number[l] = n + '0';

printf("%s\n", number);
```

Comment: You are right, I did forget to add the '\0' character at the end, but I am more confused at the fact that the array is remembering all the 2's the next time the function is called. From my understanding the next time the function is called the array should not remember the old data that was there.

Comment: In this particular simple case, with your particular compiler and settings, it just happens that the values are kept, but not always. You should assume that the array will not be remembered.

Answer (score 2):

> the array should not remember the old data

For each program, the C standard either:

- specifies what the program should do
- says that it is not specified what the program should do

It hardly ever says that the program should *not* do something in particular.

In this case, the standard says that it is not specified what characters should be in the array at the start of the function. They can be anything at all. Characters from the previous call is one particular case of "anything at all".

Comment: And it's trivial to fix, just initialize the array: `char number[10] = {0};`